# Getting the Width and Height of Dynamically Loaded Images?

Tags: javascript, height, width

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get image size (height & width) using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

I'm dynamically loading different images with different dimensions.

```
<img src="A.png" alt="" />
<img src="B.png" alt="" />
<img src="C.png" alt="" />
```

How can I obtain the width and height of an image using JavaScript ?

I want to check the width of an image. For example:

`if ( (width || height) < 200px)` i want to double the size of image.

Thanks in advance.